# Publishing sheets results in all errors

Tags: google-sheets, publish

I have a roster style spreadsheet from which I want to publish a few pages. I can publish most of the pages fine, but I'm having trouble with displaying the values in a few.

I've created a sheet that takes today's date and populates with the values from another sheet with today's date in its title. That way when I publish this particular sheet it will change every week, without the need to re-publish a different sheet every Monday.

The thing is, when I do publish these individual sheets every week there's no issue; but when I try and publish this automatically updating one every cell with values just contains `#VALUE!`, with a couple of `#REF!` errors.

This doesn't make sense to me, as they contain the same values. The only difference is that one has values that populate from other sheets (but even the ones that are working have some cells that update from other sheets, and they work fine!)

EDIT: When using `ImportRange()` to try and port the data to another sheet a few cells display: the ones only locally referencing this particular sheet, and not calling information from elsewhere.

Comment: But I'm not trying to publish any finance data, right? Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's essentially a list of names in sheet1. A small section of that list is then displayed in sheet2 (say rows A - K), so that when I change them in sheet1 they also change in sheet2. I'm then trying to publish sheet2, and that's causing errors.

Comment: The document link is no longer valid. Error is: `You need permission to access this published document.`